# Making the action bar shown by startActionMode() show as an overlay?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

For an activity with `NoActionBar` in its theme, an action bar is still shown temporarily when calling `startActionMode()`.

Is it possible to make the temporary action bar shown use an overlay? Setting `windowActionBarOverlay` in the theme does not affect the action bar shown by `startActionMode()`.

Comment: are you using any toolbar ?

Comment: No, just a view filling the whole layout.

Comment: set this <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item> and let me know ,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make contextual actionmode bar overlay my layout instead of "pushing" it down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473185/how-to-make-contextual-actionmode-bar-overlay-my-layout-instead-of-pushing-it)

Comment: thanks :) bdw I didn't see that duplicate question :)